# How to install a new version of ubuntu over an already double boot ubuntu/windows?

Tags: boot, system-installation, lubuntu

here is my question:
I've installed ubuntu in a partition of the same disk where it is windows 7.
Now i've grub that allows me to choose between windows and ubuntu.
I would like to replace this ubuntu version with another fresh one because i think it is too heavy for my hardware. I don't want to install just the lubuntu desktop but i would like to perform a fresh and complete install of Lubuntu instead.
Will Lubuntu new installation replace the ubuntu without any problem? For example will i have to reconfigure grub or the new installation will manage it?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new installation will take care of the grub entries. Make sure to install the bootloader in the MBR.

Just be careful while partitioning because if you have only a single`/` partition, you will lose all data that is present in your present home folder. just back it up and start off with Lubuntu installation.

Comment: i'm not going to modify partition, i want to use the partition i've been using for ubuntu and erase everything in there. Is it correct/possible right?

Comment: yes. that is completely possible.

Comment: Ok, i would like to flag this post like "answered" but i cannot do it because i'm a novice. Thank you! Bye