# Is it possible to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on D Drive without SWAP Drive?

Tags: 16.04, lts

I have windows 7 Ultimate on my COMPAQ CQ61 laptop. I have used old version of Ubuntu (might be 13.something) which I directly installed on D drive (long back). I want to use 16.04 LTS now but needs to do lot of preparation first (Disk partition, SWAP Drive, etc.) Can I simply install Ubuntu 16.04 directly on D Drive without doing any partition and SWAP Drive?

Comment: If you mean without SWAP partition, yes, it possible. But in same filesystem with windows 7 - no.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install a new version of ubuntu over an already double boot ubuntu/windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/548707/how-to-install-a-new-version-of-ubuntu-over-an-already-double-boot-ubuntu-window) Ubuntu 16.04 uses a swap partition, and new installations of 17.04 and later use a swap file instead of a swap partition.

Answer (score 0):

Windows and Linux need separate partitions, because they use incompatible File Systems. This separate partitions can be marked on same or separate physical drives.
In minimal case you just need add separate partition to install Ubuntu near with Windows partitions. In this case you need to force to share some free place of windows file system on disk for Linux (if this drive is single on your machine and installation should be made on the same). To prevent SWAP partition or some another exotic partitions, when you start install just do not create SWAP partition in options and told installer install OS to single partition. Ubuntu finish install and setup OS boot and select loader.

*Be careful But some HP and Compaq computers have little bit non-standard disk partitions by default. For example hidden partition with Windows recovery installer..*

Comment: @Devendra As I remember all you need to choose "advanced" at the step when installator want to choose disk, You'll see simple partition manager, where just choose old ubuntu partition(is it ext4?) or delete exactly that one partition and create same new, then choose it to install. Avoid to use whole disk. No more partitions required.

Comment: Will this affect to my HDD ?

Comment: Affect like any another data changing. But not physically, if you mean that case.